# Migrate from Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu Server 18.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, server

I want to migrate from Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to Ubuntu Server 18.04.1. Do I need to re-install Ubuntu completely or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel), a Debian/Ubuntu tool installed by default on server editions and that is useful to manage multiple related packages.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your update-manager config:

```
sudo apt nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

find line `Prompt=lts` change it to `Prompt=normal`

then

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade
```

now your release is following normal release cycle instead of long term support

now you can remove desktop by executing:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop
```

after command is finished:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to get rid of leftover packages. Now you have ubuntu server. Main difference between server and desktop is just desktop packages.